# Measure that counts entries that contain a specific string

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am making a report in which I have to show the take-rates of different items. Each item exists of a three letter string, and all items are pooled in one and the same column as a large string, separated by spaces.

I am now trying to create a measure such that searches for a specific item in this column and counts in how many entries the string was found. I now that this is possible by creating a calculated column to find the entries that contain that item and then sum this column, however, it would be nice if this is achieveable in a measure.

For example, a column could contain

7AX 4U6 4U7

5AZ 6AT 4U6

609 606 543

I would then like to be able to count how much entries contain 4U6 by a measure...

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If that column is named `Table1[Strings]`, then you should be able to use this measure:

```
= COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1, FIND("4U6", Table1[Strings],,0)>0))
```

This counts the rows of the table where it's filtered to have only the rows where the string contains "4U6". (`FIND` returns the index of that substring with the last argument being what it returns if the substring is not found.)

---

Another way to do this is to coerce the conditional Boolean to be 0 or 1 and use a sum instead:

```
= SUMX(Table1, 1*(FIND("4U6", Table1[Strings],,0)>0))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alexis. This worked for me. I am wondering: the 'larger than' that follows the FIND, it causes all rows that were not found to be ommitted from the COUNTROWS?

Comment: @DriesWeytjens That's correct. It will filter out any rows from the table where `FIND(...,...,,0) = 0` before it counts.